# Which loop optimization is the compiler performing here?

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, optimization

Suppose the following code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

long long int partialSum(const std::vector<int>& v, int begin, int end) {
    long long int sum = 0;
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        sum += (v[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(10000000, 1);

    //2 threads
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::future<long long int> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, partialSum, v, 0, 10000000 /2);
    std::future<long long int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, partialSum, v, 10000000 / 2, 10000000);
    volatile long long int a = f1.get() + f2.get();
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono:: duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "With 2 threads-> " << duration.count() << std::endl;

    //1 thread
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    volatile long long int b = partialSum(v, 0, 10000000);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "With 1 thread-> " << duration.count() << std::endl;
}
```

And the output for my machine (VS2019):

```
With 2 threads-> 35477
With 1 thread-> 7000
```

Note that I had to add `volatile` to avoid more optimization being performed by the compiler.
Also note that I know that there is an `accumulate` in the `std`, but I'm currently learning about multithreading and this was a POC.
Basically, I want to know which kind of optimization the compiler is doing here, because it's optimizing it really well compared to the threaded version.
When I change `partialSum` and replace the operation (maybe `log10`), then the threaded version is twice as better as the regular one.

Edit:
After some suggestions, I changed the code to the following one:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

long long int partialSum(const std::vector<int>& v, int begin, int end) {
    long long int sum = 0;
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        sum += (v[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(10000000, 1);

    //2 threads
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::future<long long int> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, partialSum, std::cref(v), 0, 10000000 /2);
    std::future<long long int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, partialSum, std::cref(v), 10000000 / 2, 10000000);
    volatile long long int a = f1.get() + f2.get();
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono:: duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "With 2 threads-> " << duration.count() << std::endl;

    //1 thread
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, partialSum, std::cref(v), 0, 10000000);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "With 1 thread-> " << duration.count() << std::endl;
}
```

And output:

```
With 2 threads-> 11835
With 1 thread-> 0
```

Comment: Switch the order around (1 thread first, 2 threads second) ... do you get the same or similar results?

Comment: @ChrisMM yes, really similar

Comment: There could be two things: the function is actually quite fast, and the overhead is from thread launch (I do not know how long it takes, it also depends on your operating system); since probably the log10 example takes much longer, the overhead is not important anymore. Other thing could be that somehow the threads interfere with each others cache line (I do not know if this is possible); but for cheap functions operating on memory, cache is king.

Comment: @lalala I still think there is probably something going behind the scenes here. It could be the overhead from the thread creation/control, but I don't think its related with the cache.

Comment: If you tell the 1 thread version to use `async` as well, you'd likely see a large increase in time too. 
What are the compiler options you're using?

Comment: Each thread gets its own stack, and on Windows the default [thread stack size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-stack-size) is 1MB, so there should be no cache line collision for writes to local variables inside `partialSum()`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen if `sum` or `i` are actually in memory, the compiler deserves to be fired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance gap is there because you are actually copying the vectors here:

```
std::future<long long int> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, partialSum, v, 0, 10000000 /2);
std::future<long long int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, partialSum, v, 10000000 / 2, 10000000);
```

Use `std::cref` to pass them by const reference:

```
std::future<long long int> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, partialSum, std::cref(v), 0, 10000000 /2);
std::future<long long int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, partialSum, std::cref(v), 10000000 / 2, 10000000);
```

Then try measuring the performance again. For me, 2 threads version is faster after making this change. Try it here: [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/hTxqEh)

Your second snippet is printing `0` for 1 thread because you are not waiting for `f1` to finish.

put this before getting the `end` value:

```
volatile long long int b = f1.get();
```

---

As for the loop optimization (this part maybe unnecessary for the OP) the compiler(GCC) is vectorizing the loop(without any `-march=` option). The generated asm looks like:

```
.L399:
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        movdqa  xmm2, xmm4
        add     rax, 16
        pcmpgtd xmm2, xmm0
        movdqa  xmm3, xmm0
        punpckldq       xmm3, xmm2
        punpckhdq       xmm0, xmm2
        paddq   xmm1, xmm3
        paddq   xmm1, xmm0
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jne     .L399
```

We can make it a bit easy for compiler to optimize this further if we use `int` instead of `long long int`. The asm output is then reduced to:

```
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
.L13:
        movdqu  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rdx]
        add     rdx, 16
        paddd   xmm0, xmm2
        cmp     rcx, rdx
        jne     .L13
```

Comment: I see, the performance increases this way, but using your link I'm getting With 2 threads-> 5834

With 1 thread-> 5333

Comment: There's still the thread creation overhead, for me it is `With 2 threads-> 5956

With 1 thread-> 6140` and sometimes `With thread 1` is faster

Comment: please see my edit, I also created another thread for the 1 thread version with async, and check the results.

Comment: Seems you're right. f1.get() waits for the result, there is no need for a wait(), but the problem is that I wasn't doing get() for the 1 thread version. If you want to add this to your answer I will accept it.